# Is there a way to convert indentation style of other's source code to a different one

Tags: xcode, indentation

Tutorials by Ray Wenderlich prefer 2 spaces indentation style, but i prefer 4 spaces indentation style. When i make some change with the source code by Ray Wenderlich, the indentation style becomes mess. Is there a way to change Wenderlich's source code indentation style to a new one by one step?

Comment: You could do a Find and Replace search.

Comment: Don't copy somebody else's code.

Comment: @Tamás Zahola Thanks for your reminding. i just do some tests for language learning.

Comment: @Quill. I just want to change the indentation style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In XCode 7.1: select the part of the code that is not indented how you like, right click, then select 'Structure' and then 'Re-indent'. This should re-indent according to you default preference (see 'Preferences', 'Text Editing,', 'Indentation').